# Remove nested squarebrackets from Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

> Blockquote

I have an array with below structure.

```
const arr = [


    [{"classification":"Scientific Response","core_san_answer":"Dosage","core_san_localization_translation":["No"],
    "core_san_verbal_only":"false","id":"176776","major_version_number":"1","minor_version_number":"0",
    "name":"General Info Test 2","response_type":["Pharmacokinetics and Pharmacodynamics"],"size":25432,"subtype":"Local",
    "title":"General Info Test 2","type":"Medical Information"}],
    
    [{"classification":"Scientific Response","core_san_answer":"Dosage","core_san_localization_translation":["No"],"core_san_verbal_only":"false",
    "id":"176775","major_version_number":"1","minor_version_number":"0","name":"General Info Test",
    "response_type":["Pharmacokinetics and Pharmacodynamics"],"size":25427,"subtype":"Local","title":"General Info Test","type":"Medical Information"}]


]
```

I want to remove the nested squarebrackets, so that the expected result should be like the below one

```
const arr = [

{"classification":"Scientific Response","core_san_answer":"Dosage","core_san_localization_translation":["No"],
"core_san_verbal_only":"false","id":"176776","major_version_number":"1","minor_version_number":"0",
"name":"General Info Test 2","response_type":["Pharmacokinetics and Pharmacodynamics"],"size":25432,"subtype":"Local",
"title":"General Info Test 2","type":"Medical Information"},

{"classification":"Scientific Response","core_san_answer":"Dosage","core_san_localization_translation":["No"],"core_san_verbal_only":"false",
"id":"176775","major_version_number":"1","minor_version_number":"0","name":"General Info Test",
"response_type":["Pharmacokinetics and Pharmacodynamics"],"size":25427,"subtype":"Local","title":"General Info Test","type":"Medical Information"}]
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Expected result is not a valid javascript object.

Comment: Your expected result is invalid because a variable can only hold a single value at a time. Might be a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info)? Please provide more information.

Comment: sorry all, just edited the question.. it was wrong.
Please help me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is illogic to think about removing the outer most brackets... But the inner arrays are holding only one object, so you may want to remove those.

The structure would be:

```
[
  {},
  {}
]
```

instead of:

```
[
  [
    {}
  ],
  [
    {}
  ],
]
```

So you can use a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) method to obtain that result:

```
arr.map(item => item[0])
```

```js
const arr = [
  [{
    "classification": "Scientific Response",
    "core_san_answer": "Dosage",
    "core_san_localization_translation": ["No"],
    "core_san_verbal_only": "false",
    "id": "176776",
    "major_version_number": "1",
    "minor_version_number": "0",
    "name": "General Info Test 2",
    "response_type": ["Pharmacokinetics and Pharmacodynamics"],
    "size": 25432,
    "subtype": "Local",
    "title": "General Info Test 2",
    "type": "Medical Information"
  }],

  [{
    "classification": "Scientific Response",
    "core_san_answer": "Dosage",
    "core_san_localization_translation": ["No"],
    "core_san_verbal_only": "false",
    "id": "176775",
    "major_version_number": "1",
    "minor_version_number": "0",
    "name": "General Info Test",
    "response_type": ["Pharmacokinetics and Pharmacodynamics"],
    "size": 25427,
    "subtype": "Local",
    "title": "General Info Test",
    "type": "Medical Information"
  }]
]

let modifiedArr = arr.map(item => item[0])
console.log(modifiedArr)
```

Comment: My pleasure. And be careful next time when editing a question. It sometimes get closed a bit fast when it is unclear. ;)